# Calculating the limits

Tags: calculus, limits

Let consider $0<a_1<a_2<...<a_n$. What are the following limits
$$
\begin{array}{l}
A = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{r \to \infty } \frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{e^{ - {a_i}r}}} }}{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {a_i}{e^{ - {a_i}r}}} }\\
B = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{r \to \infty } \frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {a_i^2{e^{ - {a_i}r}}} }}{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {a_i}{e^{ - {a_i}r}}} }
\end{array}
$$

Comment: What is $a_i$?${}$

Comment: $a_i$ is just a finite constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $0 < a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_n$ and $e^{-rx}$ is a monotone decreasing function in $x$ (where $r$ is some fixed positive constant), we know that the expression:
$$
e^{-a_1r}
$$
**dominates** all other expressions of the form $e^{-a_jr}$ (where $j \in \{2,3,...,n\}$) as $r\to\infty$. So the limits $A$ and $B$ will intuitively be **the ratio of the coefficients of these expressions**. That is, you will find that:
$$
A=\dfrac{1}{a_1} \qquad\text{and}\qquad B=\dfrac{a_1^2}{a_1}=a_1
$$

To see this, multiply the numerator and denominator by $e^{a_1r}$ and exploit the fact that for any $j \in \{2,3,...,n\}$ and for any $k \in \Bbb{R}$:
$$
\lim_{r\to\infty} \dfrac{k}{e^{(a_j-a_1)r}}=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$A=\frac{1}{a_1}$$
$$B=a_1$$

$$ $$

Comment: Proof? Hint? Sketch? ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint for $A$:
$$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{e^{-a_1r}\left(1+\sum\limits_{j=2}^ne^{(a_1-a_j)r}\right)}{e^{-a_1r}\left(a_1+\sum\limits_{j=2}^n a_je^{(a_1-a_j)r}\right)}=\frac{1}{a_1}$$
$$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{e^{-a_nr}\left(1+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}e^{(a_n-a_j)r}\right)}{e^{-a_nr}\left(a_n+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1} a_je^{(a_n-a_j)r}\right)}=\frac{1}{a_n}$$

Comment: This is a solution, not a hint.